# Can i forbid vector to reallocate objects?

Tags: c++, pointers, vector, allocator

Let's say we have a vector of double (values) and a vector containing objects that store pointers to the elements of the vector of double (vars):

```
class Var
{
public:
    explicit Var(double* v) : _value(v) {};
    ~Var() {};

    const double get() const { return *_value; };
    void set(const double v) { *_value = v; };

private:
    double* _value;
};


struct Vars
{
    Vars()
    {
        //values.reserve(1000'000);
    }
    vector<double> values{};
    vector<Var> vars{};

    void push(const double v)
    {
        values.push_back(v);
        vars.emplace_back(&values.back());
    }
};
```

(objects after adding are never deleted)

It is known that when a vector reallocates objects, all pointers break.
I can pre-call reserve(), but the problem is that I don't know how many objects will be stored, maybe 5, or maybe 500'000 and shrink_to_fit() will break pointers anyway.

I can use a deque in this case, but I'm wondering if I can prevent the vector from reallocating memory when I call shrink_to_fit (), or some other way?

Comment: you could write  little wrapper class that rejects adding items once you reach a given size. In fact I see you already have done, in your push just check the size

Comment: You could use a `std::list<Var>` instead, `std::list<T>::iterator`'s are stable.

Comment: I'm confused. What do you want it to do if you try to add an object that it doesn't have room for?

Comment: yes, I mentioned that I can use deque (or list).

Comment: You can exit the program rather than reallocate?  Or do you want a std vector with unbounded contiguous storage that never reallocates.

Comment: @David Schwartz the problem is not in creating rooms, but in removing unnecessary

Comment: @Yakk-AdamNevraumont the container is used to solve systems of equations (DAE). Var class for accessing variables from the caller

Comment: @hermann.minkowski I don't understand. When you attempt an operation that the vector would have to reallocate in order to do, what do you want to happen?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The key is

> objects after adding are never deleted

Rather than store pointers/iterators/references to elements of the vector, store a pointer<sup>1</sup> to the vector and an index.

```
class Var
{
public:
    explicit Var(std::vector<double> * vec, size_t index) 
      : vec(vec), index(index) {};

    double get() const { return vec->at(index); };
    void set(double v) { vec->at(index) = v; };

private:
    std::vector<double> * vec;
    size_t index;
};


struct Vars
{
    vector<double> values;
    vector<Var> vars;

    void push(double v)
    {
        vars.emplace_back(&values, values.size());
        values.push_back(v);
    }
};
```

1. pointer and not reference so we are a [*SemiRegular*](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/concepts/semiregular) type (and can easily define `==` to be *Regular*)

Answer (score 1):

`std::vector` does not allow you to return part of its buffer to the heap while keeping the rest; there is no API in the `std::allocator` "concept" to do that.

`std::vector` guarantees contiguous storage, so it cannot be allocated in pieces.

If you don't need contiguous storage, use either `std::deque` or a hand-rolled duplicate (deque leaves some performance-critical parameters free for implementations to choose and doesn't expose the ability to configure them to end-users; so if your deque isn't appropriate for your use case, you may have to roll your own).

`std::deque` is a dynamic array of fixed sized buffers, plus a small amount of end-management state.  It allows for stable storage with a dynamic sized container and O(1) random access, and the container overhead is a small percentage of the amount stored (the scaling overhead is a pointer per block, and block size is many times larger than a pointer on every implementation I have seen).

It has the disadvantage compared to vector that the storage isn't contiguous, and that iterator/`[]` lookup has an extra pointer indirect, but it would be a strange contiguous storage container that fit the rest of your requirements.

Answer (score 0):

> Can i forbid vector to reallocate objects?

You can avoid reallocation by not performing operations which cause the vector to (potentially) reallocate.

Other than making the vector const, there is no way to prevent those operations from being performed. One solution is to make the vector a private member (and never return a pointer / reference to non-const pointing to that member), in which case you only need to be concerned that your member functions do not perform those operations.

> the problem is that I don't know how many objects will be stored, maybe 5, or maybe 500'000

If you don't need the pointers in between insertions, you can perform all insertions in one go (regardless of how many), then get the pointers afterwards, and then no longer modify the vector.

In the general case where above is not an option, if you need the pointers to remain valid, vector is not an appropriate choice of data structure. A list or deque would work depening on how you use the container.

Regarding the example: Having a vector of objects, and vector of (wrappers containing) pointers to those objects seems to be rather pointless.

Comment: the container is used to solve systems of equations (DAE). Var class for accessing variables from the caller

Comment: @eerorica  "If you don't need the pointers in between insertions, you can perform all insertions in one go (regardless of how many), then get the pointers afterwards, and then no longer modify the vector."  Variables are added at runtime, one by one